# Regular expresion problems

Tags: regex, regular-language

So I have to make a regex for the following language that checks (a|b|c)* with the propriety that the string wont end in "abc".
So I have made the following regex:

```
((a|b|c)*((a|b)+|(a|c)+|b(b|c)+))
```

which is how my teacher taught me however I tested it on https://regex101.com/
and with some more research I have learned that in theory it should be equivalent to the following regex :

```
([abc]*([ab]+|[ac]+|b[bc]+))
```

However the website does some funny things with my regex and I dont know how to use it.
So what would be the regex for my Language ?

Comment: You just replaced capturing groups with character classes, which is equivalent in what these patterns match.

Comment: Thank you , but its my regex correct ?  Uppon closer inspection I realized that instead of * I should use + so it will take at least one of the 3 options ((a|b|c)*((a|b)+|(a|c)+|b(b|c)+)) but it still regonizes abc as good for my regex

Comment: Try `^([abc]*([bc][abc]{2}|[abc][ac][abc]|[abc]{2}[ab])|[abc]{0,2})$`

Comment: Now for aabbcc it shows no match

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/t2XyQ8/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would advice to use negative lookbehind pattern (https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) to check whether string does not end with some sequence.

```
^(?:a|b|c)*(?<!abc)$
or
(?:a|b|c)*(?<!abc)
```

The processor look for text consist of `abc` and when it find the maximum string it checks, whether there is NOT `"abc"` at the end. If yes, it throws away last char and try it again and again, until it is possible to continue in following steps.

see examples https://regex101.com/r/jBIjlu/1 and https://regex101.com/r/jBIjlu/2

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate solution to Jan's answer:

```
^(?:a(?!bc$)|b|c)*$
```

It uses lookahead instead of lookbehind and it matches a full line containg zero or more "b", zero or more "c", zero or more "a" given that this "a" is not followed by a "bc" followed by end of line.